# Como solucionar el error que escribiré ne el Psot que me pasó con el código que escirbiré en el post que usé?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, xampp, mariadb

usé Xampp y como base de datos MariaDB; mesale el error al importar una base de datos sql, el cual es:

Error
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

11 values were expected, but found 10. (near "(" at position 553)
11 values were expected, but found 10. (near "(" at position 1607)
SQL query: Copy

```
-- -- Volcado de datos para la tabla `empleado` -- INSERT INTO `empleado` (`idEmpleado`, `Area`, `Cargo`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `numero`, `sexo`, `estadocivil`, `direccion`, `telefono`, `email`) VALUES (3, 'Almacen', 'coordinadores de area', 'Luis', 'Micolta', 604017, 'masculino', 'soltero', 'Carrera 64 C # 78-19 Apartamento 34', '4508469', 'luismicolta23@gmail.com'), (5, 'facturadores', 'coordinadores de area', 'Carmen', 'Buendia', 3002606640, 'femenino', 'casada', 'Carrera 37 C # 32-47 Apartamento 46', '4807245', 'carmenbuendia45@gmail.com'), (7, 'cuadrilla', 'coordinadores de area' 'Esteban', 'Cambiazzo', 4007503380, 'transmale', 'divorciada', 'Carrera 57 C # 69-12 Apartamento 50', '6702349', 'estebancambiazzo@gmail.com'), (2691, 'administrativo', 'coordinadores de area', 'Tatiana', 'Liberta', 6007905520, 'transfemale', 'viuda', 'Carrera 79 C # 12-39 Apartamento 43', '2305187', 'tatianaliberta67@gmail.com'), (27930, 'oriente', 'facturadores', 'Camilo', 'Maya', 3407781, 'masculino', 'casado', 'Carrera 36 C # 17-94 Apartamento 68', '4607354', 'camilomaya32@gmail.com'), (318057, 'occidente', 'facturadores', 'Dayana', 'Perez', 2006507790, 'femenino', 'unionlibre', 'Carrera 46 A # 80-26 Departamento 41', '5907138', 'dayanaperez28@gmail.com'), (4708913, 'norte', 'facturadores', 'Horacio', 'Gomez', 7001503360, 'transmale', 'soltero', 'Carrera 82 B # 30-59 Departamento 27', '7902695', 'horaciogamez42@gmail.com'), (5798451, 'sur', 'facturadores', 'Caterina', 'Posada', 697832, 'transfemale', 'divorciada', 'Carrera 95 E # 35-81 Apartamento 61', '3704468', 'caterinaposada78@gmail.com'), (9, 'cuadrilla', 'alcantarillado' 'Daniel', 'Giraldo', 4007503380, 'transmale', 'divorciada', 'Carrera 57 C # 69-12 Apartamento 50', '6702349', 'estebancambiazzo@gmail.com'), (2691, 'administrativo', 'coordinadores de area', 'Tatiana', 'Liberta', 6007905520, 'transfemale', 'viuda', 'Carrera 79 C # 12-39 Apartamento 43', '2305187', 'tatianaliberta67@gmail.com'), (27930, 'oriente', 'facturadores', 'Camilo', 'Maya', 3407781, 'masculino', 'casado', 'Carrera 36 C # 17-94 Apartamento 68', '4607354', 'camilomaya32@gmail.com'), (318057, 'occidente', 'facturadores', 'Dayana', 'Perez', 2006507790, 'femenino', 'unionlibre', 'Carrera 46 A # 80-26 Departamento 41', '5907138', 'dayanaperez28@gmail.com'), (4708913, 'norte', 'facturadores', 'Horacio', 'Gomez', 7001503360, 'transmale', 'soltero', 'Carrera 82 B # 30-59 Departamento 27', '7902695', 'horaciogamez42@gmail.com'), (5798451, 'sur', 'facturadores', 'Caterina', 'Posada', 697832, 'transfemale', 'divorciada', 'Carrera 95 E # 35-81 Apartamento 61', '3704468', 'caterinaposada78@gmail.com');

MySQL said: Documentation

#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 3 y el código que usé fue:  

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `empleado`
--
INSERT INTO `empleado` (`idEmpleado`, `Area`, `Cargo`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `numero`, `sexo`, `estadocivil`, `direccion`, `telefono`, `email`) VALUES
(3, 'Almacen', 'coordinadores de area', 'Luis', 'Micolta', 604017, 'masculino', 'soltero', 'Carrera 64 C # 78-19 Apartamento 34',  '4508469', 'luismicolta23@gmail.com'),
(5, 'facturadores', 'coordinadores de area', 'Carmen', 'Buendia', 3002606640, 'femenino', 'casada', 'Carrera 37 C # 32-47 Apartamento 46', '4807245', 'carmenbuendia45@gmail.com'),
(7, 'cuadrilla', 'coordinadores de area' 'Esteban', 'Cambiazzo', 4007503380, 'transmale', 'divorciada', 'Carrera 57 C # 69-12 Apartamento 50', '6702349', 'estebancambiazzo@gmail.com'),
(2691, 'administrativo', 'coordinadores de area', 'Tatiana', 'Liberta', 6007905520, 'transfemale', 'viuda', 'Carrera 79 C # 12-39 Apartamento 43', '2305187', 'tatianaliberta67@gmail.com'),
(27930, 'oriente', 'facturadores', 'Camilo', 'Maya', 3407781, 'masculino', 'casado', 'Carrera 36 C # 17-94 Apartamento 68', '4607354', 'camilomaya32@gmail.com'),
(318057, 'occidente', 'facturadores', 'Dayana', 'Perez', 2006507790, 'femenino', 'unionlibre', 'Carrera 46 A # 80-26 Departamento 41', '5907138', 'dayanaperez28@gmail.com'),
(4708913, 'norte', 'facturadores', 'Horacio', 'Gomez', 7001503360, 'transmale', 'soltero', 'Carrera 82 B # 30-59 Departamento 27', '7902695', 'horaciogamez42@gmail.com'),
(5798451, 'sur', 'facturadores', 'Caterina', 'Posada', 697832, 'transfemale', 'divorciada', 'Carrera 95 E # 35-81 Apartamento 61', '3704468', 'caterinaposada78@gmail.com'),
(9, 'cuadrilla', 'alcantarillado' 'Daniel', 'Giraldo', 4007503380, 'transmale', 'divorciada', 'Carrera 57 C # 69-12 Apartamento 50', '6702349', 'estebancambiazzo@gmail.com'),
(2691, 'administrativo', 'coordinadores de area', 'Tatiana', 'Liberta', 6007905520, 'transfemale', 'viuda', 'Carrera 79 C # 12-39 Apartamento 43', '2305187', 'tatianaliberta67@gmail.com'),
(27930, 'oriente', 'facturadores', 'Camilo', 'Maya', 3407781, 'masculino', 'casado', 'Carrera 36 C # 17-94 Apartamento 68', '4607354', 'camilomaya32@gmail.com'),
(318057, 'occidente', 'facturadores', 'Dayana', 'Perez', 2006507790, 'femenino', 'unionlibre', 'Carrera 46 A # 80-26 Departamento 41', '5907138', 'dayanaperez28@gmail.com'),
(4708913, 'norte', 'facturadores', 'Horacio', 'Gomez', 7001503360, 'transmale', 'soltero', 'Carrera 82 B # 30-59 Departamento 27', '7902695', 'horaciogamez42@gmail.com'),
(5798451, 'sur', 'facturadores', 'Caterina', 'Posada', 697832, 'transfemale', 'divorciada', 'Carrera 95 E # 35-81 Apartamento 61', '3704468', 'caterinaposada78@gmail.com');
```

Comment: Hay que traducir los mensajes de error, que son bastante explícitos... Aparte, es más fácil mencionar el error en el título que escribir un título _clickbait_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Estaba más cool el nickname anterior. Y el error es que el script tiene problemas de sintaxis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que no escribiste bien la query, te faltan signos. Hay que aprender a traducir los errores o al menos tener el inglés básico para entenderlos. Por otro lado espero que no sean datos reales.

- Acá te falta una coma después de coordinadores de área.

```
(7, 'cuadrilla', 'coordinadores de area','Esteban'
```

- Aquí te faltaba una coma después de alcantarillado.

```
(9, 'cuadrilla', 'alcantarillado', 'Daniel'
```